# Неправильное расположение объектов в приложении

Tags: android-studio, xml, imagebutton

В Anroid Studio всё выглядит как хотелось бы, но когда приложение устанавливается на телефон, всё чрезвычайно криво себя ведёт, прошу помощи в убийстве этого нюанса.[image: скрин студии]

[image: скрин устройства без клика и ввода текста]

[image: скрин при отсутствии текста в поле]
[image: скрин при вводе текста в поле]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="false"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Darova ebatb =-="
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.506"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.95" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="396dp"
        android:background="@drawable/suslik"
        android:onClick="OnLick"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/suslik"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.461"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.849" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Введите желаемое имя"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.532"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>`
```

Comment: как здесь [говорят "спасибо"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо слишком мудрить со связями. У вас линейная зависимость - соединяйте виджеты один с другим по очереди, а не привязывая каждый к краям экрана (верх и низ). Чтобы верхний и нижний виджеты были ближе к краю, а средний занимал все пространство между ними, нужно делать привязки от среднего к крайним (а не наоборот). Хардкорить значения размеров виджетов крайне не рекомендуется. На одном устройстве 320dp - это треть экрана, на другом - целый экран, лучше использовать относительные размеры и маржины (в примере на все доступное меду виджетами пространство с учетом маржинов. Так же вы можете указать соотношение сторон картинки в разметке, чтобы она не искажалась (в примере 3:4). Не надо указывать бэкграунд и форграунд  одну и ту же картинку, это бессмысленно и только расходует ресурсы. Пример разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="false"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Darova =-="
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:onClick="OnLick"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/suslik"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="3:4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Введите желаемое имя"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, запомню на будущее.